# I want to execute this c code for hadamard matrix.and want the new code for hadamard matrix if any

Tags: c

I am trying to compile this code for the [Hadamard matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_matrix) generation. Can anyone tell why this code is not getting executed?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <conio.h>

main() {
int H_SIZE=32;  /*length of each code word: you can change. */
int n,r1,c1,i,j;
int hadamard_matrix[2][2]={{1,1},{1,0}}; /* Initialise 1x1 matrix */
for (r1=0;n<H_SIZE; r1*=2){
for(c1=0; c1<H_SIZE;c1*=2){
    while (r1<H_SIZE){
        for (i=0;i<r1;i++){ /* loop#1: Copying the code matrix itself    below for new code matrix */
            for (j=0;j<c1; j++){
            hadamard_matrix[i+r1][j]=hadamard_matrix[i][j];
        }
        }
        for (j=0; j<c1;j++){/* Loop#2: Copying the code matrix on right to itself for new matrix */
            for (i=0; i<r1;i++){
            hadamard_matrix[i][j+c1]=hadamard_matrix[i][j];
            }
        }
        for (i=0;i<r1;i++){/* Loop#3: Copying cojugate of code matrix for complentary diagonal part */
            for (j=0;j<c1;j++){
                hadamard_matrix[i+r1][j+c1]=hadamard_matrix[i][j];}}  
      }        
    }
   }
printf("%d\t", hadamard_matrix);
}
```

Comment: Does the code build? Does the program crash? Does the program generate unexpected output? Have you tried stepping through it in a debugger? Please give us more details.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/18604659/revisions check out this!

Comment: `printf("%d\t", hadamard_matrix);` ???? `main()`???

Comment: a few problems with the code:  1) nothing in the conio.h header is used and that header is not portable.  Suggest removing the #include for conio.h  2) there are only 2 valid and 1 optional ways to declare the main() function and they all have a return type of 'int'.

Comment: `r1` start `0`, update by `r1*=2` => always `0`.

Comment: for readability/understandability by us humans, please consistently indent the code.  Never use tabs for indenting as every word processor/editor has the tab stops/tab widths set differently.  Suggest 4 spaces as that is visible even with a variable width font and does not quickly eat up the available horizontal page space.  Suggest indent after every opening brace '{'  un-indent before every closing brace '}'  Suggest surround code blocks (if/else/do..while/while/for) with a blank line

Comment: for readability and ease of documentation, only place one variable declaration per statement/line

Comment: when compiling, always enable all the warnings (for gcc, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` )  then fix the warnings.  beside the above mentioned problems with the code, the second parameter to the printf() is not an 'int' and the variable 'n' is used before it is initialized.

Comment: this line: `for (r1=0;n<H_SIZE; r1*=2){` is nonsence, please re-evaluate.  amongst other things, 'n' is not initialized and 'n' is not modified anywhere in the posted code.

Comment: the posted code does not compile, so ofcourse, it does not execute.  amongst other things, the code is missing a closing brace '}' , probably before the call the printf().  consistent indenting would have told you that, as does the compiler

Comment: @user2979190: I've made the code visible in the question [Hadamard matrix code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18604659/hadamard-matrix-code) to which you referred.  It should not have been deleted.

Comment: @user3629249: actually, the number of braces is balanced.  The layout is horrid, but there are close braces at the ends of lines where no-one in their right mind places them.  The final `printf()` statement prints an address as an integer; C does not have built-in matrix printing functions.

Comment: I see... (a clear example of why closing braces should always be on a separate line, by them selves)

Comment: I  skipped commenting on the printf()) (good ol' egg on face) I did not check the end of lines for closing braces.    So here another comment:  only place 1 statement per line.  That makes it so much easier for us humans to read/understand the code.  (a closing brace is a code block closure statement)

Answer (score 0):

First of all: Run this through a compiler, I'd wager it wont compile. Enable compiler warnings.

Secondly:

```
main() {
```

That wont work. Do:

```
void main(void) {
```

Thirdly:

```
n<H_SIZE
```

Wtf is that supposed to be doing? You probably wanted to type `r1` instead. Note that also your `n` is never initialised and never used anywhere else in the code

Fourthly:

```
printf("%d\t", hadamard_matrix);
```

Thats not how printing a matrix works.

You also seem to be missing a closing brace in there somewhere.